# Have the script achieved it was supposed to please check i am a beginner

Tags: python, linux, multithreading

i am just a beginner in python.What i try'ed to achieve is making two threads and calling different functions in different thread.I made the function in thread 1 to execute  a function for 60 seconds and thread 2 to execute simultaneously and wait the main thread to wait for 70 second.When thread one exits it should also exit the second thread and finally control should come to main thread and again the call to thread one and thread two should go and same procedure repeat.
I try'ed achieving it using the below thread but i thing i was not able to

```
I have made a script in which i have started two thread named thread 1 and thread 2.
```

In thread 1 one function will run named func1 and in thread 2 function 2 will run named func 2.
Thread 1 will execute a command and wait for 60 seconds.
Thread 2 will run only till thread 1 is running .
Again after that the same process continues in while after a break of 80 Seconds.

I am a beginner in python.
Please suggest what all i have done wrong and how to correct it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import threading
import time
import subprocess
import datetime
import os
import thread

thread.start_new_thread( print_time, (None, None))
thread.start_new_thread( print_time1, (None, None))
command= "strace -o /root/Desktop/a.txt -c ./server"
final_dir = "/root/Desktop"
exitflag = 0
# Define a function for the thread
def print_time(*args):
    os.chdir(final_dir)
    print "IN first thread"
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc.wait(70)
    exitflag=1

def print_time1(*args):
    print "In second thread"
    global exitflag
    while exitflag:
        thread.exit()
        #proc = subprocess.Popen(command1,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, sterr=subprocess.PIPE)



# Create two threads as follows
try:
    while (1):
        t1=threading.Thread(target=print_time)
        t1.start()
        t2=threading.Thread(target=print_time1)
        t2=start()
        time.sleep(80)
        z = t1.isAlive()
        z1 = t2.isAlive()
        if z:
            z.exit()
        if z1:
            z1.exit()
           threading.Thread(target=print_time1).start()
           threading.Thread(target=print_time1).start()
        print "In try"
except:
   print "Error: unable to start thread"
```

Comment: Please try to come up with a title that is closer to your actual question, thanks!

Comment: Check this link. It will help with Python threading. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Answer (score 0):

I can't get the example to run, I need to change the function definitons to

```
def print_time(*args)
```

and the thread call to

```
thread.start_new_thread( print_time, (None, None))
```

then you have a number of problems

1. you are currently not waiting for the exitflag to be set in the second thread, it justs runs to completion.
2. to share variables between thread you need to declare them global in the thread, otherwise you get a local variable.
3. thread.exit() in the `print_time1` function generates an error
4. Your timings in the problem description and in the code does not match

So, to solve issue 1-3 for print_time1 declare it like (removing exit from the end)

```
def print_time1(*args):
    global exitflag
    while exitflag == 0:  # wait for print_time 
        next
    # Do stuff when thread is finalizing
```

But, check the doc for the thread module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html), "[...] however, you should consider using the high-level threading module instead."

```
import threading
...

while(1):
    threading.Thread(target=print_time).start()
    threading.Thread(target=print_time1).start()
    time.sleep(80)
```

One final tought about the code is that you should check that the threads are actually finalized before starting new ones. Right now two new threads are started every 80 sec, this is regardless of whether the old threads have run to completion or not. Unless this is the wanted behaviour I would add a check for that in the while loop. Also while you are at it, move the try clause to be as close as possible to where the exception might be raised, i.e. where the threads are created. The way you have it now with the try encapsulating a while loop is not very common and imo not very pythonic (increases complexity of code)

Comment: can you share ur mail id or send test mail at gunjanmehta08ATgmaildotcom

Comment: I have also updated the ques with the latest code can u check that